# What is it called and meaning of {//!p;} in sed

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I was looking for a sed command which can print lines next to a pattern match up to end of file.

Somehow I got this command:

```
sed -n '/pattern match/,${//!p;}' Readme
```

which does solve the purpose but I don't understand `{//!p;}`. What is it called or which is used for?

So that if I want to skip multiple lines based on different scenarios instead of just the line which has the pattern, I should be able to do that.

I know there are different commands which might solve this purpose; grep, awk are the closest. But I want to understand this approach.

Also sorry for the title of the question as I can't get any better idea how to put this query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An empty regular expression, `//`, as per the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses),

> repeats the last regular expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is passed to the `s` command)

so the command

```
sed -n '/pattern match/,${//!p;}'
```

takes an address range: from the first occurrence of a line matching `/pattern match/` to the end of the file (`$`). For each of the lines in this range, `//!p` is run; this is equivalent to `/pattern match/!p` as per above, i.e., "if the line does not match `/pattern match/`, print it".

So the complete command prints all the lines from the first occurrence of the pattern to the last line, but suppresses the ones that match. The file

```
line 1
line 2
pattern match
line 4
pattern match
line 6
```

would become

```
line 4
line 6
```

Comment: can we give some parameter to sed, so that instead of skipping just the pattern matched line, we can ask it to skip 2 or 3 subsequent lines after the match.

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh If you use GNU sed, there is an extension to address ranges that allows to do that: `/pattern/,+N` matches the line containing `pattern` and the next *`N`* lines as well: `/pattern match/,+2` matches the line with `pattern match` and the following two. To skip the line with the pattern and the two subsequent lines in the command in the answer, you could use `sed -n '/pattern match/,${//,+2!p;}'`.